# Sliding isn't quite smooth using ViewPager

Tags: android, performance, android-viewpager

When pages change, I will dynamically adjust the content of a `LinearLayout` view which is used as a page indicator.

The specific code ares is as followings:

```
public void onPageSelected(int index) {
    // ...  
    adjustPagerTab(index);
    //...
}
```

`adjustPagerTab()` is the function to dynamically change some view. It's not smooth in the end up switching pages.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If something in your own method is affecting the smoothness of the ViewPager swipe, you are most likely doing too much work on the UI thread in your adjustPagerTab method.

Have you checked out ViewPagerIndicator library?  Works great with ViewPager, and I've used it on several projects without seeing any side effects like what you described.

http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Comment: Actually,the ViewPagerIndicator library dosen't meet what I need. And when I put the adjustPagerTab method in onPageScrollStateChanged like:                   if(state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING)
   {
    adjustPagerTab(currentIndex);
   }                                                   The problem is solved，but a new one occurs.The changes of the LinearLayout view delays obviously.